# How to redeploy a free Wordpress site to another IP?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, deployment

How to redeploy a free WordPress site to another IP without changing site address? A site of my friend is deployed to the same IP address as another source which refers the drugs somehow. It led that our country blocked the whole IP address because of the law. Asked this question on WordPress forum but didn't get the answer.

Thank you,

Comment: Is this really a site hosted on `wordpress.com`?

Comment: Are you hosting the site? The only way is to move the site to another server. The Duplicator plugin is good for this.

Comment: fuxia, yes, it is hosted on wordpress.com

Comment: *Alison*, but I want to keep site address the same. Will Duplicator is capable for it and will it work for a free Wordpress website?